# HTML5 Effect GaussianBlur (also knows as "aerowindow")

Tags: jquery, html, css

there's someone who knows how to reproduce gaussian blur effect on everything behind a div tag?
I googled a lot for months and i found just the effect played over images with **canvas utilities**..but isn't what i'm looking for.
As well, **AeroWindow** plugin for jQuery is not the answer i would because it's just an opacity effect with background.
Thank U guys.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, there are some rumblings that a future CSS spec will include a blur effect. However, this is not available yet anywhere, even dev versions of the major browsers; it's really just in the open discussion phase at the moment.

The only way currently to get a blurring effect in CSS is to use `box-shadow` or `text-shadow`. These are not aimed at doing what you're trying to do. However, I can imagine that it would be possible to use `box-shadow` to achieve something like what you're after.

I've had a go with it; here's a JSFiddle of what I've managed to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Vkuks/

For reference, the code in that fiddle looks like this:

```
<div class='shadowed'></div>
<div class='background'></div>
```

```
.shadowed {
    position:absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px 10px #888888 inset;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity:.75;
}

.background {
    background-image: url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=4");
    height:61px;
    width:250px;
}
```

I don't know if this is close enough to what you're looking for? I don't think the box shadow is actually blurring the image behind it; just a fuzzy darkening effect? But it's as close as I can get with current CSS. Hopefully you might be able to tweak it from there to get something that's good enough for your needs.